# Create a font (.ttf) from a serie of vectorial images (.eps)

Tags: python, fonts, truetype, fontforge

I am working in a project to learn Kanji (equivalent of our latin letters for Chinese/Japanese except that there are more than 2000 of them) and we developed a new font for each character.

For the moment, we have all the images stored in .eps vectorial images. Did anyone know how I could stored all those vectorial images into a single .ttf or .otf font file ?

I am mainly working in Python and was thinking to write a script for it, do anyone would have a hint on how I could proceed ? I tried to search in order to understand the structure of a .ttf file but didn't manage to found a single useful source. I only heard about [fonttype](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library.

I also heard about fontforge and I was able to open a Japanese .ttf font and access about the elements but I don't understand how I can import an .eps file with fontforge to replace the vectorial model.

Answer (score 0):

Using the FontForge UI, you can use **File**/**Import** and select the EPS for the glyph.

For the rest of creating a usable font, you'll need to learn about how a font is constructed. For Kanji, learn where the Kanji are allocated to code points in Unicode, so that you know where to put each character.

I'm not familiar with fontforge+python, but I understand there is a way to write a script to automate the incorporation of this many EPS files into a draft fontforge project.